# A rope swing logic Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

There is a player and a small ball in the middle of the level, the player can only jump, and when we press the spacebar again during the jump, he must look for a ball nearby and attach a rope to it, and swing, how can I do this? are there any sources or code?

```
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float jumpforce;
    public Transform grCheck;
    public float grRadius = 0.2f;
    private bool gr = false;
    public LayerMask whatis;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        gr = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(grCheck.position, grRadius, whatis);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && gr)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpforce*100f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code only shows your jump logic. Please show your best effort in attempting to resolve the chalenge, and what is going wrong with your approach

Answer (score 0):

First add a rigid body and a collider to the object. Write the following code in "FixedUpdate", it cannot be "Update", because it is a physical property, it must be "FixedUpdate"

```
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, Vector3.up);
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        if (ground == true)
        {   

            //transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*distance, 2, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*distance));
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * mJumpSpeed);
            ground = false;
            Debug.Log("I am Pressing Jump");
        }
    }
```

"ground" is used to determine whether you are in the air or on the ground, and if it is in the air, of course, it will not let you jump. In addition, if you want to cancel the recoil, add "GetComponent().freezeRotation = true" in the "start" method;